# How to display the data once

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is the output i am getting:
[image: output i am getting]Expected Output:[image: This is my expected output]I want to display S.no,Bill no,Bill date,partyname(this datas are present in purchase bill table)only once for a same bill no and product name,Qty,Amount(this datas are present on purchase item table) to be displayed according to the product name for the same bill no..My problem is Bill no,Bill date and partyname also printing multiple times for the bill no..Below i have attached my code..what changes have to be done on my code..please help me..
Controller Code:

```
$this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
$this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('purchaseitem');
$this->db->order_by("no", "asc");
$this->db->join('purchasebill', 'purchasebill.date = purchaseitem.billdate','left outer');
$this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
$this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itcode = purchaseitem.Product_Code','left outer');
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
$data['query'] = $query;
```

View code:

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?> 
<tr>
  <td><?=$rowcount;?></td>
  <td><?=$row['billno'];?></td>
  <td><?=$row['billdate'];?></td>
  <td><?=$row['PName'];?></td>
  <td><?=$row['itemname'];?></td>
  <td><?=$row['Qty'];?></td>
  <td><?=$row['amount'];?></td>
  <?php $rowcount +=1?>
    <br>
  <?php endforeach ?>   
</tr>
```

[purchase item table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM8XD.png)i have attached my table structure[purchase bill table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Fbj.png)

Comment: Something here doesn't make sense. You appear to want each item to show up yet you don't want the `purchasebill` data to show more than once. I suggest you provide sample data and what output you expect.

Comment: Check my edited post i just want to print bill date,partyname printed once item name and quantity are printed according to the entries in a bill no

Answer (score 0):

Dhara, have you inspected the contents of `$query`to ensure that the data looks like what you are expecting?  Perhaps a temporary `var_dump($query)` prior to printing your table would lend some insight.